# MySQL Insert Column Half Inserted

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit of a weird one really, and probably something I haven't done correctly, but for some reason when I am inserting or updating in MySQL (using a PHP Class to create), for some reason the text being inserted (an HTML copy of an email in this case) is only half inserted ... it keeps breaking when it sees '–'

I do not think this is a standard hyphen since it looks ever so slightly different in the browser bar and even in this text area my hyphen '-' is narrower than '–'. I've tried HTML Entities, but will not convert, so an suggestions when dealing with this troublesome character?

Though I should probably say, if I use PHP My Admin to directly insert the HTML body (exactly the same formatting, everything gets inserted. I've even tried `str_replace` to remove it with no luck. I've also replaced words with a lot more words but that worked (yet it still cut off before that character showed.....

Comment: any code? what have you tried?

Comment: Is the column defined wide enough in the database to hold all of the text your inserting?

Comment: Yes, it is defined as `LONGTEXT` which is plenty long - but like I said above, if it pasted the data into PHP My Admin, everything is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a "[dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)" not to be confused with a hyphen. Look at the difference: – -

There are many kinds of dashes:

```
figure dash    (‒)  U+2012              
en dash        (–)  U+2013
em dash        (—)  U+2014  
horizontal bar (―)  U+2015
swung dash     (⁓)  U+2053
```

You can try to `str_replace("–", "-", $query);` for each type before executing the query and see if that solves your problem, but really you should look into possibly doing a [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and then setting your database field to use UTF8.

Comment: This sounds like the most likely cause (which does Outlook make dashes instead of hyphens?) - I will see what I can do

Comment: Outlook will autoconvert a double hyphen (--) to an em dash, which is what it looks like you are getting. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/autocorrect-and-the-em-dash/6b4b0e83-2bb1-4d1b-9346-384596fd48d7

Comment: Thanks - it seems to work! Are there any other characters that could break the insert like this?

Comment: I'm sure there are. It really depends on the character encoding the table expects and what you give it. Maybe this will provide more insight: http://www.bluebox.net/news/2009/07/mysql_encoding/